# Selecting models by substraction between their datetime-fields

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have a mySQL table named 'schedule' which has fields *time_start* and *time_end* in datetime format.

I need to get models from database which substraction will be greater than 4 hours in Ruby on Rails context. For example:

```
Schedule.where("#{time_end} - #{time_start} > 4.hours")
```

How can I do it with Active Record? If it impossible then how I can do it with mySQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you use mysql this would work.

```
Schedule.where("DATE_SUB(time_end, INTERVAL 4 HOUR) > time_start")
```

reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: I believe `INTERVAL 4 DAY` is not an exact equivalent of `> 4.hours`.

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware or Rails (and I believe it’s impossible with Rails), but it’s easily doable with SQL:

```
Schedule.where("TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, time_end, time_start) > 4")
```

[`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has two functions for difference between dates:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2007-12-31 10:02:00','2007-12-30 12:01:01');
-- result: 22:00:59.


SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2007-12-30 12:01:01','2007-12-31 10:02:00'); 
-- result: 79259  the difference in seconds with the time.
```

You could use something like:

```
Schedule.where("TIMESTAMPDIFF(time_end, time_start) > 240")
```

Not sure if that works, but you could give it a try. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could use MySQL's [`TIMEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) function:

```
Schedule.where("TIMEDIFF(time_end, time_start) > '04:00:00'")
```